# Highlight sidebar items on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

To put it simple, I have a sidebar with a list of categories. In the body I have a number of cards listed where each card corresponds to one of the categories in the sidebar list.

Goal: As I scroll the page I want the correct category in the sidebar to be highlighted.

Attempt: I have attempted for a while in this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/ZEKjvOd?editors=0010), but somehow I cann't seem to get it just right.

Here's my code:

```js
    /* Menu - Show active */
    const newsItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    function highlightMenuItem() {
        newsItems.forEach((el) => {
            let bounding = el.getBoundingClientRect();
            let elementHeight = el.offsetHeight / 2;

            if (bounding.top >= 0 && bounding.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) + elementHeight) {
                let activeMenu = el.getAttribute('data-category');
                document.querySelector('.' + activeMenu).classList.add('menu-active');
                console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.menu-active'));


                 if (document.querySelectorAll('.menu-active').length > 1) {
                     document.querySelectorAll('.menu-active')[0].classList.remove('menu-active');
                 }

            } else {
                let inActiveMenu = el.getAttribute('data-category');

                if (document.querySelector('.' + inActiveMenu).classList.contains('menu-active')) {
                    document.querySelector('.' + inActiveMenu).classList.remove('menu-active');
                }
            }

        });
    }

document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    highlightMenuItem();
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}    

.menu__list {
        background-color: #fff;
        display: flex;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 50px;
    }

    .menu__item {
        border: solid 1px #000;
        flex: 1 1 0;
        border-top: none;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .3s;

        a {
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 10px;
            line-height: 1.8;
            letter-spacing: -0.2px;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        span {
            transform: rotate(-90deg);
            display: block;
        }

        &.menu-active {
            color: #fff;
            background: #000;
        }
    }


.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  padding-right: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}


.item {
  text-align: center;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="menu__list">
    <div class="next-space menu__item">
      <a href="{{link_url::288}}#next-space"><span>Space</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="next-intelligence menu__item">
      <a href="{{link_url::288}}#next-intelligence"><span>Intelligence</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="next-mobility menu__item">
      <a href="{{link_url::288}}#next-mobility"><span>Mobility</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="next-security menu__item">
      <a href="{{link_url::288}}#next-security"><span>Security</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="next-medtech menu__item">
      <a href="{{link_url::288}}#next-medtech"><span>Medtech</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="next-money menu__item">
      <a href="{{link_url::288}}#next-money"><span>Money</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item next-space" data-category="next-space">Space</div>
  <div class="item next-space" data-category="next-space">Space</div>
  <div class="item next-space" data-category="next-space">Space</div>
  <div class="item next-space" data-category="next-space">Space</div>
  <div class="item next-intelligence" data-category="next-intelligence">Intelligence</div>
  <div class="item next-intelligence" data-category="next-intelligence">Intelligence</div>
  <div class="item next-intelligence" data-category="next-intelligence">Intelligence</div>
  <div class="item next-intelligence" data-category="next-intelligence">Intelligence</div>
  <div class="item next-mobility" data-category="next-mobility">Mobility</div>
  <div class="item next-mobility" data-category="next-mobility">Mobility</div>
    <div class="item next-security" data-category="next-security">Security</div>
  <div class="item next-security" data-category="next-security">Security</div>
  <div class="item next-security" data-category="next-security">Security</div>
  <div class="item next-security" data-category="next-security">Security</div>
  <div class="item next-mobility" data-category="next-mobility">Mobility</div>
  <div class="item next-medtech" data-category="next-medtech">Medtech</div>
  <div class="item next-medtech" data-category="next-medtech">Medtech</div>
  <div class="item next-medtech" data-category="next-medtech">Medtech</div>
  <div class="item next-medtech" data-category="next-medtech">Medtech</div>
  <div class="item next-medtech" data-category="next-medtech">Medtech</div>
  <div class="item next-medtech" data-category="next-medtech">Medtech</div>
  <div class="item next-money" data-category="next-money">Money</div>
  
  

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use isInViewPort function, with this you can determine a html element is on the screen or not. So you can highlight your sidebar items.

```js
function isInViewport(element) {
    const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
        rect.top >= 0 &&
        rect.left >= 0 &&
        rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
        rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
    );
}
```

pass the html element to the function, function will return true or false, true is on the screen and false is not on the screen. İf you controll this when user scrolldown on the page you can highlight the correct sidebar item.

also can check this link:
https://www.javascripttutorial.net/dom/css/check-if-an-element-is-visible-in-the-viewport/

Comment: This is a useful function, thank you, but doesn't quite help my case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a modern way to achieve this if you're still having this issue - use the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Their docs state:

> Implementing intersection detection in the past involved event handlers and loops calling methods like Element.getBoundingClientRect() to build up the needed information for every element affected. Since all this code runs on the main thread, even one of these can cause performance problems.